# Getting distorted svg circles after a lot of zooming in

Tags: svg, raphael, viewbox

I am using raphael to create svg circles. I am also doing zoom and pan using setViewBox as suggested in http://jsfiddle.net/9zu4U/10/ . Actually my problem is like I create a circle on screen and clicking on that circle creates 20 smaller circles inside the bigger circle. So I zoom in and I click on any of the smaller circles. It creates 20 circle inside that circle. And I zoom in and so on. But after 6-7 levels it gives me distorted circles and hexagons. What could be the reason of this? It doesn't happen in Mozilla.

I tried creating a very big paper and a very big circle initially and displaying it zoomed out so it fits the screen. Just to ensure that the radius of smallest circle don't go in decimal values.

EDIT : example [jsfiddle.net/LbcPd/3](http://jsfiddle.net/LbcPd/3) .

Comment: More details needed. It doesn't work in what browser? Please post an example.

Comment: It doesnt work in Chrome, IE and safari. Didn't try with opera.

Comment: Added example here http://jsfiddle.net/LbcPd/1/ . Problem occurs after 7-8 levels. i.e when you click a circle-click inner circle- click inner circle an so on for eight times

Comment: Are you trying to break Raphaël? :) Your initialzoom of 100 in the updated example seems like it probably isn't enough. 8 full cycles of zooming through this is like 6 orders of magnitude. You're pushing the limits of rounding error!

Comment: I am not trying to break Raphael. It is kind of project requirement. I have tried with more initialzoom (like 100000). But that also does not help.